# Make multiple replacements in a list by index

Tags: prolog

I have this program that makes multiple replacements in a list given by 
    another list with pairs in the format (Index, Elem).

```
Example:
replace_multiple([A, B, C, D, E], [(2, b), (1, a), (3, c), (4, d)]).
###
should result:
####
Lst = [a, b, c, d, E],
false
####
However this is my output:
A = a,
B = b,
C = c,
D = d
false
####
What am i doing wrong?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am i doing wrong?

Here are a few things:

- You may be unsure about the fact that the list you want to replace contains elements starting with uppercase letters, i.e. logical variables.
- In `replace_multiple/2`, the new element is described as `Elem` in the head, but as `Letter` in the body.
- In `replace_multiple/2`, the call to `replace/4` has `Lst` on first and second position. The meaning of a logical variable like `Lst` is the same as the name of a shared global variable, which, however, cannot be modified unless you replace more logical variables in that logical variable with other stuff. So you have the same  structure as "input" and "output". This is probably not what you want.
- Same for `replace_multiple/2` per se, which should take `Lst` and build ("return") a modified `LstMod` given as third argument.
- There is fat syntax error at the end of `replace/4`.
- It is better to use `[x,y]` or `x-y` than `(x,y)` as a notation for a pair.

Comment: In the point 2 it was just poor edit by me, I just wanted to change some of my variables to make a more general question. I was able to solve the problem by adding a new variable as input  Result. I change it to this: `replace_multiple(Lst, [(Index, Elem) | R], Result)` and then unified it at the end with `replace_multiple(Result, [], Result).`. I also changed the argument of replace as you said in point 3 changing it to `replace(Lst, Index, Elem, NewLst)`. Thanks for the help :).

Comment: @jose Excellent. Remember to [write unit tests](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/plunit.html%27)) to keep the train on the tracks.